# Remove the mention text in Angular mention

Tags: html, angular

I'm trying to use the angular mention lib and here is the demo URL:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mentions

I want to clear the selected item if there is any change from the original name

eg: the original name is **@Jacob**. If I remove "**ob**" character, the selected name should be removed

[image]

Do we have the library or tips to support this one? Thanks.

Comment: Its a bit confuse trying to guess whats in your code. Could you please share your code and what you have tried so we can have more information

Comment: Hi @SrArkaitz, I mean Do we can do like as this demo https://afry.github.io/quill-mention/. The selected item will be in the block and we can remove it